# Tools for analyzing performance of SQL Server/Express?

Tags: database-performance, sql-server-2005

The application that I have customized and continue to support for my client is seeing dramatic performance problems in the field. Simple queries on rather small datasets take over a minute when I would expect them to complete with sub-second times.

My current theory is that SQL Server Express 2005 is too limited for the rather non-trivial  demands being made of it, but I am not sure how to get about gathering data that I can use to either prove my point or allow me to move on to finding another cause.

Can anyone point me toward some tools that would allow me to analyze the load on this database? Information such as simultaneous connections, execution times of individual queries, memory usage, heck just any profiling data at all would be a help.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perfmon and dmv stats

See [this MSDN blog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jimmymay/drum-roll-please-the-debut-of-the-sql-dmv-all-stars-dream-team) by Jimmy May.

Answer (score 0):

Perfmon for sure.  [This link](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/) to Brent Ozar's blog gives details on setting up the counters and such.